# Accidentally delete xcodeproj file, what should I do?

Tags: xcode

As the title states, I accidentally deleted my xcodeproj file. I was basically trying everything possible to stop xcode from loading a cached version of my project onto my device.

What can I do? I can no longer open my project in XCode obviously, how can I rebuild this file?

Comment: Restore it from your TimeMachine backup, revision control repository, or some other backup.  You do have backups, right?

Comment: Yes, my last backup is a few days old though, does it matter? What does this file hold exactly?

Comment: It's just a bunch of data about the project. You can look at the files it contains in a text editor. It should be fine to use the one from backup.